# SQLAlchemy querying the wrong table using route

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to pass a `user_id` through the below form action button

```
<form action="{{ url_for('users.user_delete', user_id=user.id)}}" method="POST">
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete">
</form>
```

then i'm using the below route to query the user and delete from db

```
@users.route("/user/<int:user_id>/delete",methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def user_delete(user_id):
   user = User.query.filter_by(id=user_id).first()
   db.session.delete(user)
   db.session.commit()
   flash("User has been deleted", "success")
   return redirect(url_for('users.admin_panel'))
```

However, for some reason, it is querying the other table and this is the error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError:
>   (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: post.user_id
>   [SQL: UPDATE post SET user_id=? WHERE post.id = ?] [parameters: (None,
>   2)] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/gkpj)

Comment: It looks like the User you're trying to delete has Posts, and the `user_id` in Posts can't be null. You should configure your models so deleting Users deletes linked Posts instead of trying to set the related Post `user_id`s to `NULL`. See https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/cascades.html.

Comment: if i switched it to null, i can delete it normally!
do i have to change the query in the route to get the user

Answer (score 1):

You cannot delete a user if it still has posts connected to it, because the posts won't have an author which is prohibited by your `Post` model. You can prevent this by first deleting the users posts and then the user, or by setting `nullable` parameter to `True` at the `user_id` column in the `Post` model

I think thank something like this should work:

```
user = User.query.filter_by(id=user_id).first()
db.session.delete(user.posts)
db.session.delete(user)
db.session.commit()
```

Comment: so, i can delete posts for that user first then delete the user, 
do i have to change the query or remains the same

Comment: I've added some code which I think might work, but I'm not sure since you haven't posted your models.

Comment: You can also adjust the User model to enable cascade deletions which will automatically delete all children/orphans as required (make sure you think through the results though!) https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/cascades.html